# Пропадает сессия при обновлении и страницы

Tags: php, сессия

Написал в первом файле `session_start();` в сессию записываю имя при авторизации и перекидывает на вторую где я авторизован. Возвращаюсь на первую страницу сессия видна через `print_r($_SESSION);` И когда делаю обновление страницы сессия пропадает( почему так?

Блин нашел ошибку: у меня в кнопке `onclick="<?php unset($_SESSION['admin']); ?>"` и из-за этого почему то исчезала сессия.

Тогда вопрос: Как тогда мне удалять сессию по нажатию на button? если onclick не подходит

Comment: Вы вот думаете, что команда unset() должна сработать при клике в браузере, но нет! В браузере не может php работать :) Php код интерпретатор обрабатывает при выводе страницы пользователю. Откройте хотя бы html код страницы и посмотрите, что у вас в `onclick` написано.

Comment: ну а как можно сделать?

Comment: Заводите отдельный файл или функцию с кодом разрушения сессии на который/ую у вас должна существовать отдельная ссылка. Эту ссылку и должны в браузере использовать для выхода.

Answer (score 2):

В onclick обработчике либо делайте AJAX запрос на страницу закрытия сессии, либо явно переходите на эту страницу. А уже на этой странице должно выполняться

```
unset($_SESSION['admin']);
```